Differential ageing between exposed paper and ballpen ink soaked paper
I've been looking at what is the state of the art for evaluating lower bounds of the age of a ball pen signature for forensic purposes. This is my first question in this SE, and I thought it was the closest fit for this question.
Most of the literature seems to focus on determining the ageing of the ink itself: observing phenoxyethanol traces seems to work well enough for up to 24 months after the signature. Signatures older than that presumably have most of the measurable volatile evaporated.
I've seen some papers that use high pressure liquid chromatography with UV detection that can work for older signatures, but as far as I've been able to investigate, it is only reliable to measure differential ageing between two signatures on the same document, and proving they weren't written at the same time.
What I haven't been able to find is some other way that relies on estimating differential ageing between exposed paper and paper (either immediately under or soaked by) the signature ink. This seems appealing if possible because if the paper soaked by the ink is better preserved from oxidation, then it can prove that the signature is older than what the document is claiming to be.
Is there something similar to what I'm describing?
